# Set default login/authentication in server.xml. How can you do this?

Tags: web, websphere, websphere-7, websphere-liberty, server.xml

Extract from my server.xml :

```
<basicRegistry id="basic" realm="customRealm">
     <user name="defaultUser@example.com" password="password" />
</basicRegistry>
```

Currently, this requires login from the user in the form of a dialog box.

I would like for the user to be logged in as `defaultUser@example.com` by default, without any dialog boxes or having to type anything.

How can I do this?

Comment: Whats the point of security then? Maybe just disable application security and then all your users will access application anonymously. Maybe I'm missing something you are trying to accomplish here...

Comment: @Gas Thanks for the response. It's merely for demo/learning purposes. I want to create a demo where the user is "always logged in" as this one user. I have lots of ruby code built on top of grabbing the name of the currently logged in user - that all works great - now I just want to remove the need to actually fill in this dialog box so I can send it out into the wild ! :)

Comment: ...could I just put it in an iFrame?! EDIT : No. There's something wrong with putting it in an iFrame. I don't know what it is, but there is definitely something wrong with this - can anyone remember what I am thinking of? Oh God it's 2AM. OK. Sorry for going insane StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use this kind of link to provide authentication credentials in it:

```
http://userid:secretpassword@yourHost/context-root
```

Check if it will work and is good enough for your case.

UPDATE

1) The other solution could be to implement FORM login. So you need to change security settings in your application and add following to the web.xml

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>login.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
 </login-config>
```

Then you would need to send `POST` request to

```
http://yourHost/context-root/j_security_check
```

with `j_username=userid`  and `j_password=password`

2) Second solution which would would work totally seamlessly would be to create custom TAI like described here - [Developing a custom TAI for the Liberty profile](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dev_custom_tai.html?lang=en)

Relevant code fragment from that page:

```
import com.ibm.wsspi.security.tai.TrustAssociationInterceptor;

public class SimpleTAI implements TrustAssociationInterceptor {
...
   public TAIResult negotiateValidateandEstablishTrust(HttpServletRequest req,
                    HttpServletResponse resp) throws WebTrustAssociationFailedException {
        // Add logic to authenticate a request and return a TAI result.
        String tai_user = "taiUser";
        return TAIResult.create(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, tai_user);
    }
```

Add the TAI class to the Liberty profile server.
Use one of the following methods to add the TAI class to the Liberty profile server:

- Put the custom TAI class in a JAR file, for example simpleTAI.jar, then make the JAR file available as a shared library. See Configuring TAI for the Liberty profile.
- Package the custom TAI class as a feature. See Developing a custom TAI as a Liberty profile feature.

Comment: Thanks for this, I figured this was one method I could use...unfortunately in firefox this makes the user click a dialog box and so I am still searching for a more seamless solution. I'm amazed I can't find any way to do this in websphere. It is so simple in IIS and Apache!