# Removing authentication in Websphere

Tags: web-services, security, websphere, websphere-liberty, server.xml

Currently my server.xml contains this :

```
<basicRegistry id="basic" realm="customRealm">
  <user name="user@example.com" password="test"/>
</basicRegistry>
```

I would like to always be logged in as user@example.com without the need for any credentials to be entered.

How can I accomplish this by editing my server.xml or in some other manner?

Comment: Added some options here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25538674/3701228. TAI option will do what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set default login/authentication in server.xml. How can you do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531193/set-default-login-authentication-in-server-xml-how-can-you-do-this)